# On premise azure devops and microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-devops-server

Is it possible to integrate an on premise instance of azure devops with Microsoft teams? I've seen there are the azure pipelines and other such apps, which look to do exactly what we want, but they only seem configurable with azure devops Services (cloud based). Also I've seen references to a Microsoft teams integration app, but that no longer seems to exist. Any help / advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check Azure DevOps Server, it will be used to do integration with on premise azure devops.

[image]

Comment: Thats brilliant thanks Vijay. I'm struggling to find this Azure Devops Server app. Is it available yet, and if so where / how do i get it? Many thanks.

Comment: Its available in the Team connector. Pls check the steps here [link](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/teams/). In the connector search for Azure Devops Server.